# Connecting to SQL Server with PDO on WHM/Cpanel

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server database using PHP PDO. My website is hosted on a WHM/cPanel server with Centos OS. We are using PHP version7.0. The database is hosted on a Windows VPS in the same environment. We installed the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and we are now getting the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HYT00] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

The code I am using to test this out is

```
$hostname=111.111.111:1433';
$dbname='dbName';
$username='user';
$password='Secret';
$driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}';;
try {
$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$driver;Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);

echo ' <b>Connection successful</b>';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' <br> ';
}
```

I tried a couple of known credentials for the database, and I confirmed the credentials are correct, so that is not the cause.

We also tried the following commands to resolve it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

but this did not work either.

Is there a way to troubleshoot whether the issue is on the database side or on the WHM, and what the issue may be?

Comment: Yes, we can access it externally. We are using MS Access from employees' laptops to access the database.

Comment: It say "Login timeout expired ", please check your application server firewall (make sure port 1433 is open for outbound connection to the MS sql server), also please check whether the IP address is correct "x.x.x.x:1433"

Comment: We just double-checked port 1433 is open on the WHM and the VPS; and unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you tried `Server=tcp:111.111.111,1433;`? If that doesn't work then you may need to [setup /etc/odbc.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connection-string-keywords-and-data-source-names-dsns) and use an alias instead.